# Lotus email client issue

Tags: email, lotus, email-client

I am using LOTUS email client. We have an  .NET application  that send email notification to certain users on some operation. EMAIL client showing WRONG data sometimes . Lets say user XYZ is in  TO field and I am in CC field of an email. But when I open the email in LOTUS client , MY name appear both in TO AND CC field :( .

Can any one help ?

Comment: I'm sure someone can help but we need more details. Show us the code that sends the mails, for instance.

Comment: I donot think there will be any issue in code. As it is working fine for OUTLOOK , WINDOWS LIVE EMAIL . There may be some setting issue in LOTUS client

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about any settings on Lotus Notes client which are related to the problem with `to` and `cc` fields you described in your question.

Most probably your code composes email message incorrectly (from Lotus Notes/Domino's point of view), and the client represents the mail document as you described.

In the Lotus Notes client, open mail database, open email document properties and inspect two fields:

1. `SendTo` (it is shown in "To" field when you open an email document in Lotus Client)

[image: SendTo contents]

2. `CopyTo` (it is shown in "Cc" field when you open an email document in Lotus Client)

[image: CopyTo contents]

Check contents of every field (blurred on my example pictures to do not reveal email addresses in public, in your case there will be (should be) correct email addresses).

If there are correct email addresses and when you open email document it shows incorrect addresses in `To` and `Cc` fields, then it is a bug in Lotus Notes Mail Database. While it is possible it is improbable for this particular case from my point of view.

If there are not correct information in these fields, then your code composed this email document incorrectly. And you need to inspect your code and change it.